# Implication in using Knockout.js in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I see lot and lot of advantage in using Knockout.js in my MVC project but before going for it I want to make sure if there are any implications of using the same, or precautions to be taken while using Knockout.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KnockoutJS is included by default starting with ASP.NET MVC4, so it's safe to say that you're going to see it a lot in ASP.NET MVC going forward.

Ultimately there aren't any conflicts of any sort that you have to worry about with Knockout with ASP.NET MVC. It doesn't conflict with any of the DataAnnotations or other auto-scaffolded JavaScript.

You don't get any knockout scaffolding for free (not like DataAnnotations and jQuery validation) so you only use it in instances where you explicitly code it into a view or partial yourself.

I use Knockout heavily in MVC4 and in Node.JS applications and it works great in tandem with jQuery - never ran into any issues with it on either platform.

Comment: Thanks!! and does we have to perform any security measures for using it as we can passing model to Server and Save it in database, this being done by all Ajax call

Comment: Put everything over SSL if you're transmitting sensitive information - it's no different than any other client library in that regard. Never trust anything from the client.